# ClearCase + integration from source + dependency management

Tags: clearcase, dependency-management

In the industry I work in it's customary to do integration from source (i.e. compile all libraries from scratch). This means that the source code tree has to  be configured to show the appropriate content.

I know that for binary integration there a lot of tools out there, tailored to the programming languages (Maven, CMake, Gradle, etc.).

We use base ClearCase as a source control tool. How does one go about implementing dependency management when integrating from source? In ClearCase I would imagine this entails setting up the config spec to select the required versions of all of the required files. Are there any tools out there that implement this?

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any tools out there that implement this?

Yes: [ClearCase UCM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/c_ccucm.htm), meaning *not* base ClearCase.

Building from different version of "components" (group of files) is why you have the notion of:

- UCM components
- baseline: a label applied on *all* files in an UCM component)
- stream, which lists the exact foundation baselines you need for your program to work, or in your case, for your CI to take place.

Any UCM view on an UCM stream would generate the right config spec for you.

This is what a CI engine like Jenkins would use with [JENKINS ClearCase UCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin).

Comment: I was expecting this answer. As mentioned before, my organization is against moving from Base ClearCase to UCM :(

Comment: @TudorTimi I understand. That being said, for source dependencies... Git is pretty nice too ;)

Comment: I heard bad things about Git submodules due to the diamond dependency problem. Does UCM have this as well?

Comment: @TudorTimi no both for Git or UCM: the idea is to have one project with all the dependencies flatten as a single list of tags, so no diamond issue: you must agree on a canonical list of tags.

Comment: I guess this works for continuous integration, but we're not doing that.

Answer (score 1):

UCM does make this easier. But if your organization is politically averse to trying it, you can do a lot of the same thigs using base clearcase.

Streams are not much more than branches with additional metadata added on (activities, timeliness, baseline links, etc)

Baselines are essentially labels with more metadata. That metadata connects baselines to descendant and sibling baselines, and let's you have a baseline that maps baselines across components. It also links baselines to streams so you can't delete a baseline used by a stream.

You don't need UCM to do UCM-like things, it just takes more time and isn't as nicely encapsulated.

Comment: I'm assuming that there isn't any resource that details this (what attributes to add and such), right?

Comment: Sorry for the long lag. There are a couple of older books on SCM practices with ClearCase. For example: https://www.amazon.com/Software-Configuration-Management-Strategies-ClearCase/dp/0321200195

SCM really hasn't changed much since the same questions always need to be answered: 
 Who changed What?
 Where are the changes? And why were they made?